How to differentiate variables from div created by for loop in PHP with the same name?
I am writing a website that will use data from the localhost db and loop it through to create different cards where user can click on, using PHP and HTML.
 <?php
$userEmail = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from tbltrips where user = '$userEmail' order by dateEnd desc");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
for($x = 0; $x < $num ; $x++){
    ?>
    <center>
        <div class="tripOverviewContainer">
            <div id="tripOverviewContainer_imgCont">
                <?php $_SESSION['coverImg'] = $rows[$x]['coverImg']; ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $rows[$x]['coverImg'] ?>" alt="pic" style="width:100%" id="imgCont">
            </div>
            <p style="display:none"><?php echo $rows[$x]['tripID'] ?></p>
            <?php $_SESSION['location'] = $rows[$x]['location']; ?>
            <h3 style="text-align:center;" id="lblLocation"><b><?php echo $rows[$x]['location'] ?></b></h3>
            <div id="lblTravelDates_Container">
                <?php $_SESSION['dateStart'] = $rows[$x]['dateStart']; ?>
                <h3><b><?php echo $rows[$x]['dateStart'] ?></b>
                </h3>
                <h3 style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 30px">to</h3>
                <?php $_SESSION['dateEnd'] = $rows[$x]['dateEnd']; ?>
                <h3> <?php echo $rows[$x]['dateEnd'] ?></h3>
            </div>
            <p id="lblDesc">
                <?php $_SESSION['description'] = $rows[$x]['description']; ?>
                <?php echo $rows[$x]['description'] ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div id="dividerLine"></div>
    </center>
<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'document.getElementsByClassName("tripOverviewContainer").onclick =function(){';
    echo "console.log($rows[$x]['location'])";
    echo "}";
    echo '</script>';
} ?>

and the result turned out as what I wanted it to be :

The name and location and image is all at the right div in the right location, however, the div is all under the same class name, and I cannot do an onclick function with JS on each individual div that can lead me to another page for each specific card.

The problem is: The div is displaying different values as expected, but the name of each div is the same, therefore, I cannot use the JS onclick function with any individual divs.
Thank you very much.

The problem isn't clear.  You say the issue is with JavaScript but there isn't any JS in your code segment.  Please edit your question and add in the relevant JS.  Also. please explain what the issue is with binding a click event to the class?  Are you getting an error?  A result you don't expect?  Or what?

@devlincarnate Sorry for the unclear question, basically each div have the same name and but different values. When I try to write the onclick function for the div, it doesn't work because all the div have the same class name. I don't get any error, nothing gets executed.

You haven't shown us any onclick function or how you're attaching it. We can't debug the onclick if we can't see it.

@mykaf I have just edited the code that is attached to the post. The echo part in the bottom is the JS

If the problem is in the javascript and not the php, please show the rendered php and js so we can easily recreate the problem

Your script is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Even if you are escaping variables, its not safe! You should always use prepared statements and parameterized queries in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating variables into the query.

IDs must be unique. You can't use the same ID for the DIV each time through the loop.

document.getElementsByClassName() returns an HTMLCollection, not a single element. You'll need to iterate over it to assign your onclick function. There's probably an error message in your dev console.

And if you iterate over it in JavaScript, you can't use the current element of the PHP loop.

Put the variable data in a data-XXX attribute of the DIV. Then make the click listener fetch that attribute.

There is an error message in my dev console, and I am sorry I am new to PHP, what do you mean by iterate over it in JS? Do you mean using like a loop through all the divs and get each index?

Please read the documentation for document.getElementsByClassName(); it generates an array-like structure (not an actual array), so you can't just assign an onclick to the entire thing since it's not an element itself.

Put the location of in a data attribute of the div. Then loop over all the divs, adding a listener that gets this attribute and logs it.
I've removed the IDs from the HTML, since duplicate IDs aren't allowed.
I've also removed the assignments to the session variables. It makes no sense to do this in a loop, since it just overwrites the session variables each time. The final result would just be that the session variables contain the values from the last row, which is probably not what you want.
And I've replaced the query code with a prepared statement to prevent SQL injection.
<?php
$userEmail = $_SESSION['userEmail'];
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "select * from tbltrips where user = ? order by dateEnd desc");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userEmail);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
foreach ($rows as $row){
    ?>
    <center>
       <div class="tripOverviewContainer" data-location="<?php echo $row['location']?>">
       <div>
       <img src="<?php echo $row['coverImg'] ?>" alt="pic" style="width:100%">
       </div>
       <p style="display:none"><?php echo $row['tripID'] ?></p>
       <h3 style="text-align:center;"><b><?php echo $row['location'] ?></b></h3>
       <div>
       <h3><b><?php echo $row['dateStart'] ?></b>
       </h3>
       <h3 style="margin-left: 30px;margin-right: 30px">to</h3>
       <h3> <?php echo $row['dateEnd'] ?></h3>
       </div>
       <p>
<?php echo $row['description'] ?>
       </p>
       </div>
       </center>
       <center>
       <div></div>
       </center>
<?php 
}
?>
<script>
document.querySelector(".tripOverContainer").forEach(div => 
  div.addEventListener("click", (e) => console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.location)));
</script>

